# Trying to filter out items from a deeply nested sub array of objects, keep getting property doesn't exist and empty array response

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects each with its own subarray of objects.

I'm trying to filter through each of the subarrays and remove any element that doesn't match the condition `expired === false` but I keep getting an error that says: `Property 'expired' does not exist on type '{ name: string; expired: boolean; }[]'.ts(2339)` empty array and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-monad-pyzfu?file=/src/App.tsx)

My function is this:

```
result.filter(files => files.files.expired === false)
```

Here's what the parent object structure looks like:

```
const result = 
[
  {
    type: "Documents",
    files: [
      {
        name: "file_1",
        expired: true
      },
      {
        name: "file_2",
        expired: false
      },
      {
        name: "file_3",
        expired: false
      },
      {
        name: "file_4",
        expired: true
      },
      {
        name: "file_5",
        expired: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    type: "Images",
    files: [
      {
        name: "file_1",
        expired: true
      },
      {
        name: "file_2",
        expired: false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: when you got to `files.files`, at this point `files` is an array of object, so you need to loop through `files`.

Comment: files itself is an array. You need first to map through the items, and then use filter for each item. `result.map(item => item.filter(x => x.files.expired === false))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're filtering the `result` array, not the sub-arrays.

This will filter the `files` arrays in place in the `result` array

```js
const result = [{
    type: "Documents",
    files: [{
        name: "file_1",
        expired: true
      },
      {
        name: "file_2",
        expired: false
      },
      {
        name: "file_3",
        expired: false
      },
      {
        name: "file_4",
        expired: true
      },
      {
        name: "file_5",
        expired: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    type: "Images",
    files: [{
        name: "file_1",
        expired: true
      },
      {
        name: "file_2",
        expired: false
      }
    ]
  }
];

result.forEach(el => el.files = el.files.filter(file => file.expired === false));
console.log(result)
```

This will create a new array of new objects:

```js
const result = [{
    type: "Documents",
    files: [{
        name: "file_1",
        expired: true
      },
      {
        name: "file_2",
        expired: false
      },
      {
        name: "file_3",
        expired: false
      },
      {
        name: "file_4",
        expired: true
      },
      {
        name: "file_5",
        expired: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    type: "Images",
    files: [{
        name: "file_1",
        expired: true
      },
      {
        name: "file_2",
        expired: false
      }
    ]
  }
];

new_result = result.map(el => ({ ...el,
  files: el.files.filter(file => file.expired === false)
}))
console.log(new_result)
```

Comment: Hmmm the ```.forEach()``` and filter method still returns ```undefined```

Comment: `forEach()` doesn't return anything, it modifies the objects in place.

Comment: I've added executable snippets showing that it works.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have files.files as array , so you have to first loop over it and then do filter, something like

```
result.map((files) => files.files.filter(file=> file.expired === false));
```

Comment: This will lose the `type` property in result.

Comment: Tried this and it lost the ```type``` property. When I used ```.forEach()``` it returns ```undefined```